# angular4- Do i need to install ng-bootstrap if i created project using bootstrap 4 alpha theme

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

**I am using SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4-master theme in angular4.**
Theme has link to https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/
I want to use bootstrap modals in my code.
I used modals as per documentation in the theme.

For the same i used

```
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

in app.module.ts

Then i had to install ng-bootstrap via npm as it was not working.

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

When i installed ngbootstrap, webpack was being removed..

```
Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
```

I installed webpack again as per [Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179531/error-cannot-find-module-webpack-lib-node-nodetemplateplugin)

Now i am getting error this error when i open that module where i have used modal code..

```
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NgbModalStack!
injectionError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58005:90
noProviderError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58043:12
../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/</ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._throwOrNull@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59485:19
../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/</ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59524:20
../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/</ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKey@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59456:20
../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/</ReflectiveInjector_.prototype.get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59325:16
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66317:12
_createClass@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66363:113
_createProviderInstance$1@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66328:26
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66313:17
../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/</N…
Stack trace:
resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6634:31
resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6605:17
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6683:17
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6264:17
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:60717:24
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6263:17
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6031:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6441:25
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6342:21
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7266:9
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7284:17
  core.es5.js:1020
```

**Do i need to install ng-bootstrap if i am already using a bootstrap theme to use bootstrap components?**

HTML code

```
<div class="tableinfowrap">
  <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-10"><h3>Tables</h3></div>
        <div  class="col-xl-2"> <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['addresttable']" role="button">Add Table</a> </div>
      </div>

  </div>
<table class="card-block table table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Table Number</th>
    <th>Sitting Capacity</th>
    <th>QR Code Url</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let table of tablelist" >
<tr>
<td>{{table.tableNumber}}</td>
<td>{{table.seatingCapacity}}</td>
<td>{{table.qrCodeUrl}}</td>
<td ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></td>
<td (click)="open(content)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
</div>
```

.ts file code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { classToPlain } from 'class-transformer';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {TablesbyResId, ResTablesData} from '../../model/TablesbyResId';
import {TablebyResIdService} from '../../services/TablebyResIdService.service';
import { NgbModule, NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tableinfo',
  templateUrl: './tableinfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tableinfo.component.scss'],
  providers: [TablebyResIdService ,NgbModal]
})
export class TableinfoComponent implements OnInit {
  tablelist: ResTablesData[];
  deletemodal = false;
  message: boolean;
  closeResult: string;
  constructor(public router: Router, public tablebyresidservice: TablebyResIdService, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.tablebyresidservice.getTablebyIdApi()
    .subscribe(
      res =>
          {
              const tableResponse = plainToClass(TablesbyResId, res as Object)
              console.log(tableResponse);
              if (res.error === true){
              alert(res.message);
              console.log(res.message);
              console.log(res.statusCode);
              console.log(res.error);
              /* this.router.navigate(['/login']); */
          }
              else
              {
                console.log("api hit success");
                this.tablelist = tableResponse.data;
              }
      },
       error => {this.tablebyresidservice.throwError(error);},
       () => {}
      );
  }


   open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
        this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
}

private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
        return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
        return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
        return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding bootstrap itself instead of ng-bootstrap? `npm install bootstrap --save`?

Comment: will it work with bootstrap 4 theme

Comment: yeah, not sure if `npm install bootstrap --save` installs v4 yet but if not, just specify the beta version of 4

Comment: thats not working..

Comment: does it install bootstrap v4 beta?

Comment: yes it installs bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
modified error..please have a look

Comment: the alpha isnt the same as the beta but its still good enough, you then need to import the bootstrap css files in your styles.css/styles.scss file `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`

Comment: i have styles folder with bootstrap files in it as i am using theme

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `ng-bootstrap` if you want your modal in Angular way. And your theme uses it.

While going through similar problems this `NgbModule.forRoot()` seems to be the fix.

But if that not help you, i saw this error `Uncaught (in promise)` in your log. may be using `ModalDismissReasons`.

In my project i used `NgbModalRef` you can try below code.

your import look like this `import {NgbModal, NgbModalRef} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

define `modalReference: NgbModalRef;` in your class `TableinfoComponent`

now this is how your `open(content)` look

```
open(content) {
    this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content);
    this.modalReference.result.then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
}
```

remove all other code including `getDismissReason` and try.

works for me, hope this will help you.

Comment: i created project by bootstrap theme as mentioned in question
and demo modal in working in other module

Comment: theme is based on alpha version

Comment: your theme has `NgbModalStack` which is not yet supported in `ng-bootstrap` check this [link](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/643)

Comment: please provide your themes doc link

Comment: i checked github repo. your theme not using `ng-bootstrap` or `ngx-bootstrap`.  [link](https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: post some more related code, how you implemented modal. and relevant package.json info

Comment: You don't need to import NgbModule in your ts file.

Answer (score -1):

ng-bootstrap is a series of widgets that use bootstrap4.0.css. When we install ng-bootstrap we need ONLY the bootstrap.min.css.

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

We can download bootstrap.min.css and, e.g. if we are using angular-cli modified the "styles" tag in angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      ],
```

bootstrap is a series of widgets + bootstrap.css. When we install bootstrap we don't need import bootstrap.min.css

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2
```

Both them have modals

Comment: i am already using SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4 (bootstrap theme)
i created new project on this theme
do i need to install ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap??