# Running Existing Angular Project locally

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

I am very new to Angular, I am trying to run an existing project of Angular on my machine. I have done a lot of tests and followed a lot of articles. But cannot run my project.

I have the project files like this:

[image]

I installed the nodejs on my system.
And followed the following instructions as per an article:

## change directory to our repo

cd myproject

## installing Cli according to project readme file.

npm install -g @angular/cli@1.3.2

## install the repo with npm

npm install

## install TypeScript typings

npm run typings-install
-- Gives error: npm ERR! missing script: typings-install

## Then I try the following:

npm install --global
For following:

```
webpack (npm install --global webpack)
webpack-dev-server (npm install --global webpack-dev-server)
karma (npm install --global karma-cli)
protractor (npm install --global protractor)
typings (npm install --global typings)
typescript (npm install --global typescript)
```

## start the server

```
npm start
```

-- Gives multiple error messages:
Such as:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

-- For this I tried "npm cache clean" and then deleted "node_modules" and then installed packages again using: "npm install --save"

Then tried again: `npm start` it gave me same error "`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`"

Also, this error message:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
```

For this, I tried "npm uninstall -g webpack"
and then: npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli html-webpack-plugin webpack-dev-server webpack-dev-middleware from this: [Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179531/error-cannot-find-module-webpack-lib-node-nodetemplateplugin)

Tried running it again:

this time it gave me following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/post
css-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./sr
c/styles.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

For this "`Cannot find module 'node-sass'`" I did the search again:

and found this command: npm install node-sass

i tried it and then tried starting again

Now I received `ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.`

And for this I tried the following from git cli issues 8798

remove the node_modules folder

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

remove the webpack

```
npm remove webpack
```

clean npm cahe

```
npm cache clean --force
```

install the latest version of angular cli

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

install the dependencies

```
npm install
```

now it's just testing

```
npm start our ng serve
```

Now it start giving me: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found and wont work at all.
To resolve this: I did: n`g update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4`

Which remove the error: "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found" but now it gives me error

```
ERROR in src/app/web-player/albums/album-context-menu/album-context-menu.compon
nt.ts(13,14): error TS2515: Non-abstract class 'AlbumContextMenuComponent' does
not implement inherited abstract member 'getAllTracks' from class 'ContextMenuC
mponent<Album>'.
src/app/web-player/artists/artist-context-menu/artist-context-menu.component.ts
13,14): error TS2515: Non-abstract class 'ArtistContextMenuComponent' does not
mplement inherited abstract member 'getAllTracks' from class 'ContextMenuCompon
nt<Artist>'.
src/app/web-player/context-menu/context-menu.component.ts(58,34): error TS2304:
Cannot find name 'TrackList'.
src/app/web-player/playlists/playlist-context-menu/playlist-context-menu.compon
nt.ts(15,14): error TS2515: Non-abstract class 'PlaylistContextMenuComponent' d
es not implement inherited abstract member 'getAllTracks' from class 'ContextMe
uComponent<Playlist>'.
```

What am i missing here? I tried a lot of articles from 3 days but cannot run it.

Also, I see different types of Warning and messages.
[image]

Read Me file in project:

```
# Client

This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.3.2.

## Development server

Run `ng serve` for a dev server. Navigate to `http://localhost:4200/`. The app will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.

## Code scaffolding

Run `ng generate component component-name` to generate a new component. You can also use `ng generate directive|pipe|service|class|guard|interface|enum|module`.

## Build

Run `ng build` to build the project. The build artifacts will be stored in the `dist/` directory. Use the `-prod` flag for a production build.

## Running unit tests

Run `ng test` to execute the unit tests via [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io).

## Running end-to-end tests

Run `ng e2e` to execute the end-to-end tests via [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/).
Before running the tests make sure you are serving the app via `ng serve`.

## Further help

To get more help on the Angular CLI use `ng help` or go check out the [Angular CLI README](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/README.md).
```

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build --prod --sourcemaps --build-optimizer",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^3.3.3",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.3.4",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^0.8.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "raven-js": "^3.18.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "svg4everybody": "^2.1.4",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.1.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/popper.js": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/youtube": "0.0.31",
    "@types/clipboard": "^1.5.35",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-filter": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-svgmin": "^1.2.3",
    "gulp-svgstore": "^6.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can u show us your package.json file ?

Comment: Yes, I added the package.json file details in question, kindly review.

Comment: @Kadioo thanks, but gives me the error: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Kadioo 1st ran correctly, but the other *npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' * one gave "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @Kadioo tried and it ran correctly, still gives the last error I reported in my question.

Answer (score 8):

Run the following commands

```
 npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
 npm cache verify
 npm install -g @angular/cli@next
 npm update
```

Then

```
 ng serve
```

I hope it works now. Comment if u face any error while.

Comment: I tried, now it remove the error Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found but gives this: ERROR in src/app/web-player/albums/album-context-menu/album-context-menu.compon
nt.ts(13,14): error TS2515: Non-abstract class 'AlbumContextMenuComponent' does
not implement inherited abstract member'. i have updated the details in question as well.

Comment: Oh gud. Now u dont hv any issue with the angular but with project. It is an error from the project. May be due to angular version difference.

So, is the project from git ? I mean u can share me the link and we can help u. If not show us the screen shot of the package.json file.

Comment: I added the package.json file details in question. Please check. This is not available on git, I can share with gdrive if you would like.

Comment: I had to run "npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular" before running ng serve. Otherwise this works like a charm.

Comment: What if my package.json file contain non supported packages?

Answer (score 5):

That should be much easier...

**Take your project files as is**

Run `npm install`

Since you have the `package.json` file, it will read all dependencies and install them.

Then run `npm audit fix` if needed (the terminal will tell you that).

Comment: Important note: use the correct version of node. Otherwise there might be mistakes when you run:
npm install

Answer (score 3):

try `ng serve --open`
it will compile your project and directly open in browser

Comment: Gives: 'ng-serve' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Should be `ng serve` without the hyphen

Comment: because angular-cli is not installed globally try "npm i angular-cli -g"

Comment: I tried, and gives same error as above: "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found"

Comment: Sounds like an angular 6 problem, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found

Comment: Already tried and updated the question details, please check. Thanks.

Comment: create new project by "ng new project_name" cd project_name and try again with new project ng server

Comment: @mubashermubi "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found" most probably means you launch `ng serve` from the repo root's _parent_ dir. Instead, you need to launch it from the dir where angular.json file is (the root dir). I.E. if you launched `npm install` in `.` you _need_ to do a `cd ./[prjName]` into the subdir ang-cli created during install as root for the project, before you can do `nd serve`

Answer (score 0):

rename the file `.angular-cli.json` to `angular.json` and re run the `ng serve --open` command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the path of the directory in your local

> > `cd my-repo`

2. `npm install`
3. `ng serve`  or  `ng serve --open`

You will find the Localhost then.

To clean the cache:

```
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had need to setup existing angular project.

*cli version as per your package.json file

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.3.2
```

Then

```
npm install
```

Then

```
ng serve
```

I have tested, it is working here.